# features selection embedded method showing wrong features

Tags: python, machine-learning, random-forest

in features selection (embedded method) i'm getting wrong features.

feature selection code:

```
# create the random forest model
model = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=120)

# fit the model to start training.
model.fit(X_train[_columns], X_train['delay_in_days'])

# get the importance of the resulting features.
importances = model.feature_importances_

# create a data frame for visualization.
final_df = pd.DataFrame({"Features": X_train[_columns].columns, "Importances":importances})
final_df.set_index('Importances')

# sort in descending order 
final_df = final_df.sort_values('Importances',ascending=False)

#visualising feature importance
pd.Series(model.feature_importances_, index=X_train[_columns].columns).nlargest(10).plot(kind='barh')
```

```
_columns #my some selected features
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9qIg.png)

here is the features list, as you can see **total_open_amount** is very important feature
but when I put top 3 features in my model I'm getting -ve R2_Score. but if I remove
**total_open_amount** from my model I'm getting  decent R2_Score.

my question is what causing this ?(all the data train, test are randomly selected from dataset of size=100000)

```
clf = RandomForestRegressor()
clf.fit(x_train, y_train)

# Predicting the Test Set Results
predicted = clf.predict(x_test)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an educated guess since you did not provide the data itself. Looking at names of your features, the most important features are name customers and total open amount. I suppose these are features with a lot of unique values.

If you check the [help page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) for random forest, it does mention:

> Warning: impurity-based feature importances can be misleading for high
> cardinality features (many unique values). See
> sklearn.inspection.permutation_importance as an alternative.

This is also mentioned in a publication [by Strobl et al](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1471-2105-8-25):

> We show that random forest variable importance measures are a sensible
> means for variable selection in many applications, but are not
> reliable in situations where potential predictor variables vary in
> their scale of measurement or their number of categories.

I would try with the permutation importance and see whether I get the same results.